# Crossfade between Gatsby Images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, css-transitions, gatsby

With gatsby-image, I'm swapping through some photos using `setInterval()` and changing the src, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
    intervalFunction: setInterval(this.imageCycle, 10000),
  });
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalFunction);
}

imageCycle() {
   let newImage = this.state.equiptmentCurrent + 1;
   if (newImage >= this.state.equiptmentImages.length) {
    newImage = 0;
   }
   this.setState(state => ({
     equiptmentCurrent: newImage,
   }));
}
```

render method:

```
 <IMG
   sizes={this.state.equiptmentImages[this.state.equiptmentCurrent]}
   outerWrapperClassName="coverOuter"
   position="absolute"
   style={gatsbyImgStyle}
 />
```

is there any way to put a transition on this when the source changes?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible approach:

1. Stack two  tags on top of eachother via `position: absolute`
2. Style both of them with `transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;`
3. Place a new `showFront: true` property on this.state.
4. On the componentDidMount interval hook:

   1. Update the next images sizes (via the state obj) for the component that isn't active.
   2. Add Opacity of 1 and 0 (respectfully) on each  component depending on value of showFront. You can conditionally add a new class with something like: `className={"my-image-class " + (this.state.showFront ? 'seen' : 'not-seen')}` (and reversed for the bottom image). In styled-components, can do this by passing showFront as a prop.
5. Toggle showFront via the componentDidMount setInterval hook.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my `CrossFadeImage` implementation. It similar to `img` except that it can handle the animation for you when detecting `props.src` changes and has extra props to customize the transition

[image]

```
import React from "react";

const usePrevious = <T extends any>(value: T) => {
  const ref = React.useRef<T>();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
};
const useRequestAnimationFrame = (): [(cb: () => void) => void, Function] => {
  const handles = React.useRef<number[]>([]);
  const _raf = (cb: () => void) => {
    handles.current.push(requestAnimationFrame(cb));
  };
  const _resetRaf = () => {
    handles.current.forEach((id) => cancelAnimationFrame(id));
    handles.current = [];
  };

  return [_raf, _resetRaf];
};

type ImageProps = {
  src: string;
  alt?: string;
  transitionDuration?: number;
  curve?: string;
};

const CrossFadeImage = (props: ImageProps) => {
  const { src, alt, transitionDuration = 0.35, curve = "ease" } = props;
  const oldSrc = usePrevious(src);
  const [topSrc, setTopSrc] = React.useState<string>(src);
  const [bottomSrc, setBottomSrc] = React.useState<string>("");
  const [bottomOpacity, setBottomOpacity] = React.useState(0);
  const [display, setDisplay] = React.useState(false);
  const [raf, resetRaf] = useRequestAnimationFrame();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (src !== oldSrc) {
      resetRaf();
      setTopSrc("");
      setBottomSrc("");

      raf(() => {
        setTopSrc(src);
        setBottomSrc(oldSrc!);
        setBottomOpacity(99);

        raf(() => {
          setBottomOpacity(0);
        });
      });
    }
  });

  return (
    <div
      className="imgContainer"
      style={{
        position: "relative",
        height: "100%"
      }}
    >
      {topSrc && (
        <img
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            opacity: display ? "100%" : 0,
            transition: `opacity ${transitionDuration}s ${curve}`
          }}
          onLoad={() => setDisplay(true)}
          src={topSrc}
          alt={alt}
        />
      )}
      {bottomSrc && (
        <img
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            opacity: bottomOpacity + "%",
            transition: `opacity ${transitionDuration}s ${curve}`
          }}
          src={bottomSrc}
          alt={alt}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrossFadeImage;
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit demo app on CodeSandbox]